# How do I control Selenium PDF and Excel files download behavior?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, urllib

I want to download all the tender documents from this url
'http://www.ha.org.hk/haho/ho/bssd/T18G014Pc.htm'

I'm using selenium to go through each tender links and download the files.

However, my scraper couldn't handle the Excel download behavior. 
Currently, it handles PDF files pretty well.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from urllib.request import urlretrieve



driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
# open url in browser

driver.get('http://www.ha.org.hk/haho/ho/bssd/TN_236490_000952a.htm')

# get html file source
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

# extract table
table_body=soup.find('tbody')

# extract all tender links
table_url = soup.find_all('a')
for url in table_url:
    print("Opening url:", url['href'])
    print("Subject matter:", url.getText().strip())
    driver.get(url['href'])
    # get html file source
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    # look for url links which may contain downloadable documents
    doc_urls = soup.find_all('a')

    if doc_urls[0].has_attr('href'): # some a tag doesn't have any href, so we skip
        driver.get(doc_urls[0]['href'])
        tender_document = driver.current_url
        print(doc_urls[0].getText().strip(),'.pdf', sep='')

    # loop through all urls
    for doc_url in doc_urls:
        if doc_url.has_attr('href'): # some a tag doesn't have any href, so we skip
        #open the doc url
        driver.get(doc_url['href'])
       # get the tender pdf file path
        tender_document = driver.current_url
        # download file
        folder_location = 'C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\tender_documents'
        print(doc_url.getText().strip(),'.pdf', sep='')
        fullfilename = os.path.join(folder_location, filename)
        urlretrieve(tender_document, fullfilename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [requests](/questions/tagged/requests) and [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) to download all documents:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


base_url = "http://www.ha.org.hk"
tender = "T18G014Pc"

with requests.Session() as session:
    r = session.get(f"{base_url}/haho/ho/bssd/{tender}.htm")

    # get all documents links
    docs = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser").select("a[href]")
    for doc in docs:
        href = doc.attrs["href"]
        name = doc.text
        print(f"name: {name}, href: {href}")

        # open document page
        r = session.get(href)

        # get file path
        file_path = re.search("(?<=window.open\\(')(.*)(?=',)", r.text).group(0)
        file_name = file_path.split("/")[-1]

        # get file and save
        r = session.get(f"{base_url}/{file_path}")
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: hi Sers, thanks. I tried your solution, it seems to be able to get the file name and file type right however, when I look at the files, they are not properly downloaded. Each file is of 1kb size.

Comment: It manages to download all the different files :). Could you please briefly explained how you solved this? Especially on the get file path, and save part. I would appreciate if you can point me to some resources online regarding this download issue so that I can learn the logic behind it. Thanks again!

Comment: You need python requests, for file path I used regular expressions and to save file is standard Python saving content to the file (https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python). If the answer was helpful, feel free to accept it.

Comment: The actual file path for the 3 documents doesn’t appear if I use « inspect » or view source code. Why the session function can capture these ‘hidden’ links?

Comment: You can find http://www.ha.org.hk/visitor/ha_view_content.asp?content_id=253002&lang=ENG url in http://www.ha.org.hk/haho/ho/bssd/T18G014Pc.htm. But if you open this link it automatically redirect to document itself. In browser you cannot see html of http://www.ha.org.hk/haho/ho/bssd/T18G014Pc.htm, with requests you can see

Comment: Is there any way to inspect the page without requests? Any other browser tool that allows us to see what 'inspect page' and 'view source' code can't see?

Comment: Maybe it possible do using chrome devtools network tab, but I didn’t check it.