# Errno 11001 getaddrinfo failed when looping over urls

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to extract a list of documents from some pages.

I have problem when I try to loop over a list of urls as I keep getting

```
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

Appreciate clarification on why is this the case.

If I run against one url page, there should be no problem though.

I have a separate code which uses Selenium/Webdriver however the problem with using Selenium is the download behavior for different file types.

For example, if a url brings you to a pdf file, it will open up a new page showing the full pdf file. The behavior is different if the url is linked to an Excel file.

More details can be found here [How do I control Selenium PDF and Excel files download behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57566692/how-do-i-control-selenium-pdf-and-excel-files-download-behavior/57568732)

I ended up with the suggested code below which while it may not use Selenium, it does the job at getting all the files.

Thanks!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
import os

doc_urls = ['http://www.ha.org.hk/haho/ho/bssd/18G042Pc.htm'
'http://www.ha.org.hk/haho/ho/bssd/HKWCT03018A2Pa.htm',
'http://www.ha.org.hk/haho/ho/bssd/19D070Pa.htm',
'http://www.ha.org.hk/haho/ho/bssd/NTECT6AQ011Pa.htm',
'http://www.ha.org.hk/haho/ho/bssd/T18G052Pa.htm',
]

base_url = "http://www.ha.org.hk"


for doc in doc_urls:
    with requests.Session() as session:
        r = session.get(doc)
        # get all documents links
        docs = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser").select("a[href]")
        print('Visiting:',doc)
        for doc in docs:
            href = doc.attrs["href"]
            name = doc.text
            print(f">>> Downloading file name: {name}, href: {href}")
            # open document page
            r = session.get(href)
            # get file path
            # check for attibute, if not, file doesn't exist: contact admin. but how to contact the hospital admin?
            if hasattr(re.search("(?<=window.open\\(')(.*)(?=',)", r.text), 'group'):
                file_path = re.search("(?<=window.open\\(')(.*)(?=',)", r.text).group(0)
                print(file_path)
                file_name = file_path.split("/")[-1]
                # get file and save
                r = session.get(f"{base_url}/{file_path}")
                with open('C:\\Users\\tender_documents\\'+ today_yyMMddhh + '\\' + file_name, 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(r.content)
            else:
                print(f">>> File name: {name}, href: {href}", " is missing")
                continue
```

Comment: I looped through all url in your example but couldn't reproduce the problem. I connected to every url.

Comment: Apologize, the website updates the urls constantly. I've updated the urls above with the latest ones.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a typo, you are trying to use the whole regex match:

```
        r = session.get(f"{base_url}/{file_path}")
```

Should be

```
        r = session.get(f"{base_url}/{file_name}")
```

Comment: if I use file name, the files are actually empty. All of them will have 1KB size.

Comment: can you show us the value for `f"{base_url}/{file_name}"` and `r.status_code`

Comment: r.status_code is 200, the base_url/file_name will give the path to the actual document path.